# How to import posts correctly?

Tags: import

There are 2 tasks, there is a site X on which there are 1,500 posts, each entry has a title, a thumbnail and 3 metadata.
You need to export these entries to other sites. Those. first you need to write a microapi that will generate json for example, and on the side of other sites (where you need to parse these same entries) a plugin that will receive the same json in the url and create entries.
The option of exporting xml and importing to other sites is not suitable, you just need to make a script.
I made json generation, it remains to do import of records on the basis of json. The main question is how to make imports. so that it works stably, because running **foreach** from 1500 **wp_insert_post** is not a good option, right? Please tell me in which direction to look at the implementation of such a task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always give it a try, i've imported around 300 posts at the same time before so, it shouldn't be that big of a deal. You could try the following methods if you have problems with importing them all at once.

- Try re-defining WP_MEMORY_LIMIT and increase it to i.e. 1024MB
- Try increasing the max_execution_time (Check this [link](https://thimpress.com/knowledge-base/how-to-increase-maximum-execution-time-for-wordpress-site/) for more information)
- Try to split/chunk the array in a few different arrays and add a `usleep` after every iteration

Please note that within the `foreach` `$id = wp_insert_post()` will set `$id` to the `ID` of the Post/Page that is being added. If desired you can use this variable to add i.e. meta_values, thumbnails, etc.

Good luck!